# how to hide text on a tag without removing text inside :before pseudo element css

Tags: css

I would like to hide the text inside a tag, but keep the text inside the before pseudo element, without change html and without javascript

```
<a href="#">Text to be hidden</a>
```

css

```
a:before{
    content: "I need to show up"
}
```

this wipes out all of the text

```
a {
    text-indent: -999em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

little fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5wrs1ft1/

Comment: not possible.  But if you tell us what your real constraints are, maybe we can help you do this a different way.

Comment: thanks for the help, I could make it work!

Answer (score 4):

I could make it work! https://jsfiddle.net/5wrs1ft1/4/

```
a {
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
}

a:before {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    content: "I need to show up"
}
```

!important! this wont work on every browser, it works fine on chrome on firefox, I will wait for a better answer

Comment: were you just playing around with this, or do you have a real task that you're trying to solve in this way?  I hope it's the former...

Comment: I have a task, just simplified the question to the bare problem, I had access only to css and need to change a text from a link to a fontawesome icon

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work everywhere, because some browsers have a minimum font-size set by default, or allow users to set it.  And some older browsers just handle font-size:0 wrong.

Comment: Gonna put this information, and wait for a better answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My modified solution with returning previous defined font-size:

```
<span>Hidden text</span>

span {
    font-size: 0;
}    
span:before {
    content: 'Visible text';
    font-size: initial;
}
```